# How to force delete a folder or .dll in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting "undeletable" files in Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/19460/deleting-undeletable-files-in-Vista)

I am trying to delete a folder in Windows XP but when I do, it says:

> Destination Folder Access Denied You need permission to perform this
>   action.

Is there a way to force delete this folder?  I tried right-clicking the folder, and unchecking the Read-only Attributes property, but when I close the folder properties and reopen it, it is still read-only. I verified that in the Security tab, I do have full control so I should be able to delete it.

I tried deleting the individual components of the folder and am left with 3 .dll files.  When I try to delete these, they give me the same error. How should I stop and delete these .dll files?

Comment: @moab: does that apply to XP as well? Vista and XP are a bit different.

Comment: Yes, will work for XP as well. Could not find a good one for XP specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [Unlocker](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/)

Simply right-click the folder or file and select Unlocker. If the folder or file is locked, a window listing of lockers will appear. Simply click Unlock All and you are done!

Answer (score -1):

Download Process Explorer from Sysinternals.

Run Process Explorer and search for the DLL file names. Then end the process (not the process tree) that is holding the DLLs and delete them. Restarting the process should go without issue.