# Cannot delete file named "~$test.xlsx"

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How this file got created:

1. `$ touch test.xlsx` (didn't know excel would not be able to open this file.)
2. `$ /mnt/c/Path/To/EXCEL.EXE test.xlsx`
3. I get an error in Excel so it closes.
4. File `"~$test.xlsx"` is created under the working directory.

Things I tried to delete this file:

- WSL

  ```
  rm -rf /parent-directory/
  rm -fi -- *
  rm with full path
  rm with /full/path/to/file
  ```

  `mv ~\$test.xlsx test.xlsx` (to delete it later)

  The error I get is `rm: cannot remove '~$test.xlsx': No such file or directory`
- cmd

  `del "~$test.xlsx` 
  Similar error from cmd
- Explorer

  Tried deleting from explorer but I get error 'permission denied'

I can read the file. i.e. vim, less, cat, etc

output for `$ ls -la`:

```
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Oct  1 18:25  ./
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Oct  1 18:17  ../
-rwxrwxrwx 0 root root    0 Oct  1 18:12 '~$test.xlsx'*
```

How can I delete this file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting "undeletable" files in Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/19460/deleting-undeletable-files-in-vista)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  If you pay-attention, he's using *nix-esque commands to manipulate the file.

Comment: a shot in the dark.. install the tiny midnight commander and try to delete it from there.  "sudo apt-get install mc"

Comment: Is the filesystem healthy?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It is now.

Comment: The problem is no-repro. It was solved by a reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file is a temp file created by excel..It should automatically get deleted after closing main fiie..It won't get deleted only if excel crashes or power goes off..So to delete that Open task manager, force stop excel, then delete. It should delete it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that bash is trying to interpret the '$' as a precursor to a variable name.  Try escaping the '$' and the '~', by adding a '\' character in front.  i.e.:

```
rm \~\$test.xlsx
```

or

```
rm '~$test.xlsx'
```

There is one other reason that you might not be able to delete the file.  If Excel is still running, the file might be locked by the process.  You might need to terminate excel before trying to delete the file.

Comment: Not sure. There is `~\$test.xlsx` in the question, it should work. And the error is `rm: cannot remove '~$test.xlsx': No such file or directory`. If `~` or `$` was expanded by the shell resulting in another name, `rm` would report the other name.

Comment: `rm` will not, however, report the expansion for the `~` character... which expands to the home-directory.

Comment: This will not work. And as @KamilMaciorowski has said, it is not expanding ```~``` or ```$``` at all as stated in the error message. (I've tried it before posting my question). Excel is terminated completely.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why but after rebooting the computer the file has disappeared...

This problem is now solved. I wish I knew exactly what it was.
Thanks for all who posted suggestions.

Kind regards.

Comment: You killed whatever had the file in use by power cycling the Operating System, that would explain it. If you're able to reboot, and will likely do that anyway, then perhaps you should always start with that first. If the reboot does not resolve, then post the question.